# How do I pass data from my model to my view as an object and as an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, codeigniter-2

I have the following query, which returns a single row.

MODEL:

```
function get_guide_first(){
        $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('guides_entries')
            ->order_by("guide_name", "asc")
            ->limit(1, 0)
            ->join('guides_content', 'guides_content.guide_id = guides_entries.guide_id'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Here is my controller:

CONTROLLER:

```
public function get_first_guide(){
        $page_data['guide']=$this->guides_model->get_guide_first();
        $this->load->view('guidepage', $page_data);
    }
```

I then run a foreach() loop in my view (or controller sometimes).

VIEW:

```
foreach($guide as $row){
    echo $row['guide_content'];
    $activecat=$row['guide_slug'];
 }
```

Now what I would ideally like to do is return an array back from my model but even using:

```
return $query->row();
```

returns an object rather than an array.

1)How can I return this row as a 2d array? 
e.g. so that I could echo a result in the controller as guide['col_name'] rather than guide()->col_name.

2)how would I pass the object to my view so that I could use $guide->col_name from there (I would need to pass this along eith the $page_data array)

Comment: You could build your own array in the model from the query results and return it.

Comment: Yes but it's all extra code that need updating when you add a new column. There must be a way of converting an object to an array wholesale

Comment: Use `return $this->db->get()->row()->col_name` in your model to get just the column value for the first row (if I am getting your question right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm reading your question right: You can use `row_array` instead of `result_array`

I think:
`return $query->result_array();`

returns an

```
array(
   0 => array(
      'blah' => 'blah',
      'smile' => 'smile'
   )

);
```

to return just an associated array.

row array will return

```
array(
  'blah' => 'blah',
  'smile' => 'smile'    
)
```

Comment: You sir are a superstar. Any ideas on how to get it back to the view as an object (part 2)

Comment: you can cast anny array to an object with `(object)` but codeigniter should provide a method for returning just one row as an object...

Answer (score 0):

Use row_array() in your model.. that will retrun associated array.

```
function get_guide_first(){
    $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('guides_entries')
        ->order_by("guide_name", "asc")
        ->limit(1, 0)
        ->join('guides_content', 'guides_content.guide_id = guides_entries.guide_id'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```